# Переменные среды и Program Files (x86)

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть пакетный файл, который запускает некоторые приложения. На данный момент в нем прописано примерно так

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\.....exe
```

Далее, те, кто забирают этот файл из общего хранилища (в нашем случае из SVN), правят файл на свой лад (у кого то 32 битная система и они убирают (х86) из пути. Файл сохраняется, затем, иногда по случайности возвращается в репозиторий измененным. То есть у большей части людей (у кого 64 битная система) получаются неверные пути. Вопрос, как этого избежать?

Если вместо *c:\Program Files (x86)* написать *%PROGRAMFILES%*, то у пользователей 64 разрядных систем так же будут проблемы, потому что пакетный файл выполняется 64 разрядным приложением и *%PROGRAMFILES%* превратится в *c:\Program Files*. Если же написать *%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%*, то это попросту не будет работать в 32 разрядных системах.

Еще как вариант - создать 2 файла вместо одного для разных архитектур. НО сам этот файл запускается не напрямую, а через другие пакетные файлы, а значит и для тех пакетных файлов придется это применять. То есть если есть пакетный файл и 2 пакетных файла, которые его запускают, то с поправкой на разрядность системы, получится уже 6 файлов, а это не очень хорошо.

Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Попробуйте погуглить "batch file check 32 64 bit". Мне выдало [ссылку на stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322308/batch-file-to-check-64bit-or-32bit-os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо **rogueCapella** за наводку. Использовал ответы в ссылке и привел их к решению для конкретного случая с папкой *Program Files*

```
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" (set pf=%PROGRAMFILES%) ELSE (set pf=%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%)
```